# Where to define timeout for the SSRS Report Server

Tags: reporting-services

I had someone log into the SSRS report server to test something and discovered that they had been logged in for two days.  We need that to not happen.  What setting is needed to have them get logged off after a given period, say two hours?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the Windows server?  That someone Remoted into?  If so, that's going to have absolutely nothing to do with SSRS, as that's a Windows setting (remote desktop config, rdp-tcp properties, configure your session settings there - note that my memory is of Server 2008, exact location may vary on other OS's)

Comment: SSRS does have a timeout look into the configuration files. The applications must also have a time out with an added security timeout. If you are doing this in C/S architecture then you have to make sure all time outs jives.